# How to make oracle data export to druid.io

Tags: oracle, druid

I'm using druid and imply, how to make oracle data export to druid.io? 
How to export oracle data to druid databases?

Comment: So, how to export oracle data to druid databases? @RobertColumbia

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve using following steps -

1. Export oracle data in json files, having 1 line per row with key and values and if required add additional key/values for your use case.
2. Perform a druid ingestion task on that data in druid.
3. Once ingestion completes, you can use it for querying in druid.
4. You can automate this process using some cronjob script.